# mysql stored procedure create date plus one day but time set to 00:00:00

Tags: mysql

In a mysql stored procedure, how can i put into a date variable:-

curdate()+interval 1 day but at midnight - e.g. today is 2014-09-14 13:15:23 so the variable will hold:-
2014-09-15 00:00:00

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `curdate()+interval 1 day`?

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner method would be to add zero seconds to today's date + 1 day

```
mysql> SELECT CURDATE() today,
    -> CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 0 SECOND midnight_tomorrow;
+------------+---------------------+
| today      | midnight_tomorrow   |
+------------+---------------------+
| 2014-09-14 | 2014-09-15 00:00:00 |
+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out:-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS mdate;
```